# Default Template is referred to what template file

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, default

When we made a page in the admin panel of WordPress , we had to choose the template at the right hand corner in the Page Attribute box. My question is that what template file (page.php/home.php/index.php) is referred to the Default Template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template file referred to as Default template is page.php

Comment: Yes, that I guess, suvajit. But my another query is that when we make a page (in the admin panel) for our blog then we must not choose the custom page template i.e., we have to choose the default template, right ! But as per as I know the blog page must be made with index.php or home.php. So, how can I do that ? Thanks for your reply.